# How can I run a custom shortcode function on a live site and only run if the viewer is a specific machine?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization, shortcode, ip

I wrote a custom shortcode function per the client's request. I got it to work on a stock version of Wordpress but now I need to test this on the live site. I am going to send the client the code and tell him to paste it into the bottom of the theme's functions.php file.

The problem is that I only want the code to run for the client's eyes, i.e. only his computer, in order to test the code to see if it works without error. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to wrap it in a check for a custom `$_GET` var:

```
if( isset( $_GET['showmethething'] ) ){
    // do stuff
}
```

Then add that var to whatever URL you want to trigger the code:

> http://example.com/somepage/?showmethething

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this seems like it will allow me to run it on a specific *page*. I do want to run it on a specific page (the "Contact Us" page of the live site), but I only want a specific *person* to be able to view it. So for example, I paste in the modified code that checks the page requester for my IP address. If my IP address requests the page, then the code should run, otherwise it should not. Does your answer somehow allow me to do that?

Comment: The one person you want it visible for will have to add `?showmethething` to the end of the URL to see it. You will send them the code, and the unique URL that will enable it.

Comment: Ohhhh ok. I'll try this out.